# Concerns about the FAQ about high-priority (red) flags

Tags: support, flags, spam, offensive

In the [FAQ](/questions/58032), it says

> Each flag carries an implicit downvote for calculating the post’s score; it does not affect the caster’s reputation, however.

I'm not sure what an "implicit" down vote is. Is it cast by the Community user? Can I cast an extra down-vote after that?

> Rolling back a post to a previous state will revert to the number of flags from that particular revision.

How are the extra red flags handled by the system? Do they age away immediately or are they still active while simply not counting towards the 6-flags-delete threshold?

Also, I recently raised a few spam flags. Upon confirming 2 of them, I saw a red block of square flashed quickly before the post disappeared. I didn't even had time to read it (I just saw links). Is it because my flag is the 6<sup>th</sup>?

P.S. I know the "One Question Per Post" rule on SE but I'm thinking it unnecessary to post 3 separate questions (as above). Comment if you think I should do so. If anyone can **confirm** the answers to my questions above, feel free to merge into the FAQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure what an "implicit" down vote is. Is it cast by the Community user? Can I cast an extra down-vote after that?

When you red-flag (spam or rude/abusive), the Community user will automatically cast a downvote. You can downvote in addition, but this isn't really useful.

> Also, I recently raised a few spam flags. Upon confirming 2 of them, I saw a red block of square flashed quickly before the post disappeared. I didn't even had time to read it (I just saw links). Is it because my flag is the 6th?

Yes, if your spam flag is the last one, the post will be automatically deleted; if you're still on the page, you will see some kind of an animation. This can also happen if the last flag is cast by somebody else while you're still on the page. If you have [enough reputation](/help/privileges/moderator-tools), you will be able to see deleted posts, but with a red background to differentiate them from normal posts. (In addition, the content of spam or rude/abusive posts will be hidden, and you have to click an extra link to see them.) The animation marks the transition between a 'normal' posts and a deleted one.

<sub>(I don't have any immediate references or personal experience for your second question. That's the danger of asking multiple questions at once.)</sub>